# Can I keep an unencrypted memory copy of a password?

Tags: android, security, encryption, password-protection

I want to password protect the access to my Android App.
The user can choose a password, whose hash is be stored in the DB.
When the user tries to log in, the entered password hash is checked against the DB stored one. Nothing new.
But I also want to use the user's password to encrypt data, for example to dump the DB and, in this case, I don't want the user to be forced to re-enter the password. My question is: is it safe to keep a memory copy of the unencrypted password while the user is logged-in? From the outside another process could dump the app memory, for example, and retreive the password?

Thank you

Comment: "From the outside another process could dump the app memory, for example, and retreive the password?" -- it depends on whether your attacker has access to the phone and sophisticated tools like kernel debuggers. If that is a possibility, then there are ways to get the password in memory. Otherwise, unless you screw up and publish the password somewhere accessible (e.g., an `Intent` extra), probably you are safe. The reason why we treat passwords like they are radioactive is of the risk of introducing that sort of bug.

Comment: Storing a password hash in a database is only useful for authentication (e.g. on a web server). If you want to encrypt something by that password you need a "key derivation password" that uses the password and generated a crypto key from it, so you don't have to save the password nor it's hash. Android includes some classes for Password Based Encryption `PBE`. e.g. PBEKeySpec. That would be a good starting point.